# How to get div element under many divs using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

So I am using BeautfiulSoup4 with Python and I am trying to get an element with "div class". But this element is under many divs and when I try to use "find" with BeautifulSoup, it just returns "None". The element I'm trying to get is show with class "WhatIWant" in the screenshot. Here is the screenshot of the website html:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWcfk.png)

And this is the code I use for getting that element

```
page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "lxml")
element = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "WhatIWant"})
```

Comment: You don't provide the url, so we cannot test, but did you check that `soup` does have the div you look for, i.e. if the site uses JavaSctipt you will need other tools like Selenium to scrape it

Comment: Since the ```div``` has a class ```mainRankingDescriptionText```. You can directly select it. ```element = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "mainRankingDescriptionText"})```

Comment: @buran I think that's the case. But when I disable JavaScript and reload the page, some images are gone but the text I am looking for is still there. So doesn't it show that it is not because of JavaScript?

Comment: @Ram I tried but it returns "None" as well.

Comment: @bnighted May be the site uses Javascript to load. You can use ```selenium``` as @buran suggested. Could you share the URL ?

Comment: @Ram Yes, as I said I think that might be the case but the element I want is loading when I disable JavaScript (where some other elements don't load) so doesn't it prove that it is not because of that?

Comment: @Ram this is the link: "https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/tr/AvaIanche" and the text I want is that "Platinum I". I am trying to make a Discord bot, I don't know if it changes anything tho.

Comment: @bnighted I am getting a ```403 status_code``` when I make a get request to the mentioned URL.

Comment: @Ram So does that mean it is not doable on this website?

Comment: @brighted Access is forbidden. So you cannot scrape it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.leagueofgraphs.com/summoner/tr/AvaIanche'
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find('div', {'class':'leagueTier'}).text.strip())
```

output:

```
Platinum I
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I don't know about headers much. Do I have to update that part everytime the browsers (or webdrivers) get updated or I can use it like this all the time?

Comment: You can pass whatever user-agent you want. without it you get 403 error. You can pass more headers if you want.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your web page that you request does not load that element using a simple request, some of the web pages have JavaScript, and you cant scrape it with Bs4; it may be better to use Selenium.

Test it and then send the response here comment; it may be better to send here this URL.